# Can't find IP address or hostname of Samba Share

Tags: networking, network-shares, samba

I have what may be a phantom Samba or SMB share on my network workgroup, but I have so far been unable to find out what it is. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 at my workstation but I can jump onto a Windows machine if necessary. The share or whatever it is refuses all connections and has so far thwarted my attempts to figure out which computer or device it's coming from.

Any advice would be appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an *answer*, but it's how I solved my problem.

I signed onto the server that does our DHCP and looked at `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases` - I searched for "D7CN63F1" and found a lease record:

```
lease 192.168.0.174 {
  starts 4 2019/12/12 10:08:16;
  ends 5 2019/12/13 02:48:16;
  cltt 4 2019/12/12 10:08:16;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 00:1a:a0:9d:ca:fd;
  uid "\001\000\032\240\235\312\375";
  set vendor-class-identifier = "MSFT 5.0";
  client-hostname "D7CN63F1";
}
```

MSFT 5.0 means it's Windows, 2000 or newer, so that helped - I just went around on my sneakers and looked at the hostnames of each Windows machine until I found it. It seems to be locked down as best as I can determine - it even just gives the cold shoulder when you ping it.

Anyway, I'm happy for now. Also, in general, set up meaningful host names! Although I didn't set this up. Now on to the next crisis!